# I don't get notifications from area51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, notifications, global-inbox

What I mean by notifications are reputation changes, I don't get that at all, as for notifications of new comments and the like, I get them in my inbox but no notification about that, I mean I have to open the inbox and if there is a notification from area51 then I see it there? is this a bug or status-by-design?

Comment: Probably by design, as Area51 runs on a very much outdated fork of the Stack Exchange software stack and doesn't support notifications.

Comment: `status-by-kludge`

Comment: I don't get notifications from area51 either, an incentive to be there often.

Comment: Also, when I 'Copy And Save Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts', it skips area51, but meh. It isn't that hard to do it yourself.